# Voting Badges and Deleted Posts

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-questions, electorate-badge

If I find an unsalvageable question, downvote it, and flag it for closure, would my downvote still count towards badge progress for Electorate and the like, even once the question is deleted?

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Do votes, flags, and edits on deleted posts still count towards badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125380/do-votes-flags-and-edits-on-deleted-posts-still-count-towards-badges)  The answer from there is: "Yes votes on deleted posts count"